# How to live-preview latex on vscode?

Tags: pdftex, mac, vscode, live-preview

I hope to preview LaTeX in real-time on VSCode, input tex code while outputting PDF, just like MS, and I hope there are plugins or methods that can achieve this.

I noticed that some tex editors can do it, such as Texpad for mac and Bakoma tex for windows.

Although Bakomatex can combine VScode on Windows to achieve this feature, for some unknown reason, Bakomatex is not friendly to MacOS and the software is too outdated. Anyway, I hope there can be a better way, preferably with the help of vscode.

I think there are some successful cases about previewing katex or mathjax, but I hope to be able to preview **(la)tex** because I usually encounter some complex formulas and various forms of text, and the first two cannot fully meet my output needs.

If someone could provide me with a method, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would it be possible to achieve preview if partial rendering of the PDF is done instead of global changes？

Comment: Since you seem open to possibilities on macOS other than VScode, such as Bakomatex, would MacTeX &mdash; with its front end/viewer TeXShop along with TeXLive &mdash; be acceptable substitute?

Comment: One possibility is to use latexmk with its preview-continuous mode (-pvc option). I don't know how to use that purely within VSCode.  But it could certainly be run from a terminal window at the same time as you are editing the document in VSCode.  I use it all the time for the purpose you describe.

Comment: @murray Thank you for your answer, but it seems that the function of texshop is somewhat weak and cannot meet my typesetting needs.

Comment: @JohnCollins Thank you for your answer. I know about latexmk, but I don't know how to use it in vscode, and it doesn't seem to preview very quickly. Maybe I don't know how to use it.

Comment: About slowness of updates of the preview, there are 2 main issues.  First is the responsiveness of latexmk in preview-continuous mode.  It regularly examines the source file state, and starts a new compilation if file(s) have changed. The interval between file checks defaults to 2 sec (in the variable `$sleep_time`). That's appropriate for older (slower) computers, with long compilation times. This will change: The next version of latexmk (v 4.82) will allow subsecond sleep times. I find 0.1 sec on my Mac with an M2 chip gives delightful responsiveness.  (Continuation in a 2nd comment.)

Comment: The second issue is how well the viewer updates after the pdf file changes, while continuing to display the same page as before.  Many viewers (e.g., macOS's Preview) don't do this automatically.  I've found xpdf best, since it can be updated by a command from latexmk at suitable times.  (See the latexmk documentation for details of how to configure this.)   I find this works for my needs.

Comment: @JohnCollins Thank you for your answer. I think latexmk is related to Texlive. So, how should I update the version of latexmk? I used Latex on the M1 chip and previewed the PDF inside VScode. I tried some external PDF reader APP that can be updated in real time, but the results were not satisfactory to me

Comment: @ym2333 The easiest way is to wait until the new version is on CTAN (which should be in a day or two's time) and then wait a few more days until it is in TeXLive, after which a standard update will get you the latest version.  Alternatively, you can go to https://www.cantab.net/users/johncollins/latexmk/versions.html, where a number of versions of latexmk are available, including **currently** a test version for the new version.

Comment: @JohnCollins I have updated latexmk, and they are indeed faster than before. Although they cannot fully achieve WYSIWYG, they are already very close. Thank you!

Comment: I do not use VSC very much, but I have it with LaTeX and LaTeX Worshop extensions, and  editing a .tex file a see a button to render the file and another to see the output  at the right (not in real time, but in real push the buttom, but anyway,  this is  better workflow at least for big documents). Hope this help.

Comment: @Fran thankyou！